# c program multiple sytax errors for openmp

Tags: c, syntax, openmp

I am trying to learn openMP using visual studio edition 8 but when I try to compile the simple program, am getting lots of syntax error. What has gone wrong here?

here is the file: 
**mp.cpp**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define CHUNKSIZE 100;
#define N        1000;

int main(){

    int i,chunk;

    float a[N], b[N], c[N];

    printf("a is\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)

        a[i]=b[i]=i*1.0; 

chunk=CHUNKSIZE;
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);

    return 0;
};
```

The error messages from the build log are:

```
c:\users\...\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before ';'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(15) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(15) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(17) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(17) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(17) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before ';'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
c:\users\...\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
c:\users....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(15) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(15) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(17) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(17) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\....\visual studio 2008\projects\mp\mp\mp.c(17) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a solution?

Comment: Have you included the location of `omp.h` in project settings?

Comment: Typo: You have semicolons in your #defines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macros include the ';' you inserted at the end of them. So `a[N]` expands to `a[1000;]`. Just remove those semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

A define is a preprocessor instruction and replace the all define by its content, whatever it is on the code. So if you put a semi colon, it will replace it too.

And be careful, a define which is called just N will replace every occurence of N everywhere. Even in variable or functions name ...